# Data Template not shown

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

A listbox data template doesn't show and I cannot figure out why.

If I don't use a DataTemplate and copy the contents into the control section itself, it's fine.

I don't do very much binding in XAML, I usually do it all in code. What did I do wrong?

**XAML**

```
   <UserControl x:Class="Cis.CustomControls.CisArrivalsPanel"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d" Height="296" Width="876">
      <UserControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock  Background="Blue" Text="{Binding Path=StationName}" />
                        <TextBlock  Background="Brown" Text="{Binding Path=ArrivalPlatform}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ListBox Width="487" Margin="0,66,0,33" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}">
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

**CS**

```
 public partial class CisArrivalsPanel : UserControl
    {
        public CisArrivalsPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ArrivalRowItem();

        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class ArrivalRowItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public ArrivalRowItem()
        {
            this.StationName = "Lincoln";
            this.ArrivalPlatform = "1";
        }


        private string _stationName;
        public string StationName
        {
            get
            {
                return _stationName;
            }
            set
            {
                _stationName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("StationName");
            }
        }

        private string _arrivalPlatform;
        public string ArrivalPlatform
        {
            get
            {
                return _arrivalPlatform;
            }
            set
            {
                _arrivalPlatform = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ArrivalPlatform");
            }
        }


        private DateTime _arrivalDateTime;
        public DateTime ArrivalDateTime
        {
            get
            {
                return _arrivalDateTime;
            }
            set
            {
                _arrivalDateTime = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ArrivalDateTime");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Everything I see indicates that you haven't actually put anything into the collection, so what would those binding be executed against? Try putting some items in.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I don't even see any collection object.  Also the `ItemsSource` hasn't been set.

Comment: @McGarnagle Thats pretty much what I meant...

Comment: Thanks. Appears I was thinking about it all wrong. I was expecting to see the items from the constructor appear. Now I've created a collection and added to it, it appears. @BradleyDotNET please set as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Damo No problem. Added now. Feel free to let me know if there is something you feel I missed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have everything set up, but you don't actually have any *data*.

`ListBox`, like other `ItemsControl`s acts against a collection of data, and generates an instance of the template for each item it finds.

Given that you haven't set `ItemsSource` or populated any collection I can see, you need to create a collection (probably an `ObservableCollection`) and set the `ItemsSource` to it via binding. Then add some items to it, and the `ListBox` will display them!